# Inequalities in one variable: Total revenue

Tags: algebra-precalculus

An apartment complex has a demand equation given by: p =-5x+860 where x represents the number of apartments rented and p represents the price for each apartment, in dollars. The maintenance cost equation is given by: C=120x + 6255 where C includes the cost of keeping up each unit, as well as the fixed costs to manage the building.
a. Form the total revenue function, R, for the rental of x apartments, using the formula: R= p * x, where p is the demand equation above.
R = ____________________________________________________

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: I honestly don't have a clue. I'm not sure even how to set up solving this.

Answer (score 0):

Total revenue = $xp$

That is the number of apartment rented times the price per apartment.

In this case, $p$ is a function of $x$ .

Total revenue = $x(860-5x)$

Which will give you a quadratic.  And since it is quadratic it has a vertex, and if you want to maximize revenues you will need to find that vertex.

Next you will probably look at profits.

Profits = Total revenue - total costs

and try to maximize profits.

and there is a short cut.

Profits are maximized when Marginal revenue - Marginal costs

But you might not get there.